# how to use variable value outside change function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to use selected_gender variable outside the function

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=pop_gender]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'Male') {
    var selected_gender = "gender_Male";
  } else if (this.value == 'Female') {
    var selected_gender = "gender_Female"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pop_gender" id="gender_female" value="Female">
<input type="radio" name="pop_gender" id="gender_male" value="Male">
```

Comment: Declare the variable outside the function.

Comment: declared "selected_gender" as global variable, it means declare it before start of  function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, Declare selected_gender variable before on change function called.

2, take value of clickd element in selected_gender variable

3, print that variable

Hope below code helps you to understand better.

```js
let selected_gender = "";
$('input[type=radio][name=pop_gender]').on('change', function() {
    selected_gender = this.value; //this will get value of input type is radio and name is pop_gender which was last time clicked
    console.log(selected_gender); //in side of function               
});
console.log(selected_gender); //out side of function
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input type="radio" name="pop_gender" id="gender_female" value="Female">
        <input type="radio" name="pop_gender" id="gender_male" value="Male">
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I have copied your code and tested it adding an "Inside function" and "Outside function" text to each of the console logs and it is printing just the "Inside function" for me. Why is that?

Comment: Because in the above example console log event triggers on change or click on the radio button, selected_gender  the variable is updated each time when the event is triggered. Outside function event trigger only once when the page loaded  @ADM

Comment: when submitted that time take a value of `selected_gender` its has updated value of last clicked radio button, You can not debug it using console log. form submit code should be come after on change event, 
you can ask question in stackover flow, I can not understand your exact requirement if you can share some it is better for idea.
Thanks, You can share your question link to me. @ADM

Answer (score 0):

You ***could*** declare the var outside the function:

```js
var selected_gender;
$('input[type=radio][name=pop_gender]').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'Male') {
    selected_gender = "gender_Male";
  } else if (this.value == 'Female') {
    selected_gender = "gender_Female"
  }
});
```

BUT instead check where you use it

```js
let selected_gender = $('input[type=radio][name=pop_gender]:checked').val(); 
// here use "Male" or "Female"
```

On a DIFFERENT note:

[How can I deal with diverse gender identities in user profiles?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/how-can-i-deal-with-diverse-gender-identities-in-user-profiles)